# My $_SESSION array in drupal 7 is empty after login

Tags: sessions, cookies

I tried to view the $_SESSION and $_COOKIE details by print_r ing those two arrays

But my session array is empty before and after login.

I wrote the code in template.php file.

But the user is loggin in with out any problem.

Is there any problem with my installation, am running it as `http://localhost/drupal7/`

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';print_r($_COOKIE); echo '</pre>';
```

this is the code i have written to print it.I am going thru it to know whether its session and cookie values are colliding with that of magento as i am working on single sign on into drupal and magento.

Comment: I am not sure. But by default $_SESSION variable is empty. so what else are you expecting $_SESSION variable should have? What is the code you written in template.php?

Comment: @j2r: i am editing the question with more details

Comment: sorry i am not sure about the single sign on with magento.